# Display issue in google chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

It's a little bit difficult to ask a question, because I'm using mainly templated code for the outlooks of the (personnal) website I'm conceiving.

It's a template using html5/css3 and javascript (which doesn't seem to take a part in the issue I'm having).

So here it is : in firefox and explorer, the footer displays at the bottom of the screen even when the content of the page does not go that far. But in chrome, for a reason I do not grasp, the footer displays right under the content stop, leading to an ugly blank space from the end of the page to the end of the screen. Does anyone have an idea why?

I know it's difficult to answer without code, but since I only half grasp what's happening I can't really provide more information.

Thanks in advance!

Edit : https://jsbin.com/hozudepimi/1/edit?html,output
Added a bit of code if it can help

Comment: Sadly enough, without code there is no way we can really help you. You are asking us for our best guess, but we want to help you with your _specific_ problem, so please try to post some code. Even if its whats displayed as the final output in your page source. If we don't know how its working _correctly_ in FF or Safari, how can we help you fix it in Chrome? There are so many different ways to push a footer.

Comment: "I know it's difficult to answer without code" - yep.

Comment: Can you reduce the code (the HTML markup, at least) such that only the glitch (i.e. the "ugly blank space")  shows up on a page and host it on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Added a link to jsbin